# localhost doesn't adhere to security standards error in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10

https://localhost/ on Chrome in windows 10 displays the below error:

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection

    localhost doesn't adhere to security standards.
    ERR_SSL_SERVER_CERT_BAD_FORMAT
```

I need to run my php project locally..So using https://localhost/login url . I am using Xampp apache. It works fine in firefox..But issue is only with chrome.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you followed any particullar instruction on how to set https on localhost? Is there any reason why you need to use https instead of http? What http server do you use?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have it since today in Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit), the chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost didn't help either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/sTyLejkD8NQ/bhAhmHIzAgAJ) please try the following:

> Try enabling the following in chrome://flags:
>
> chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost

Answer (score 15):

I just had the same issue, and tried chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost and it didn't help. In the end, the problem was in the antivirus software ESET NOD32. I had to disable the "Enable HTTPS checking" in WEB AND EMAIL -> WEB ACCESS PROTECTION -> WEB PROTOCOLS -> HTTPS SCANNER SETUP

Comment: it works for me but don't we have any another option to remove protection for localhost only

Comment: "Pause Protection" for Eset did not help either. Only changing setting in ESET by disabling HTTPS scan. This is important for local WEB development. Would be great to ask `ESET Antivirus` for implementation.

Answer (score 1):

It something related to google and the certificate signed incorrectly. If you downgrade your google version you will see that you use the Advance link and add the exception to the site and you can continue. For now on your test recommend to use Firefox.